# How do I write to a label Excel object property using the Interop

Tags: vb.net, excel, vba

I'm converting some vb.net code which uses Excel to use the Excel interops (version 14) which MS provides. I've succesfully coverted lots of code, but I have one last problem, I can't set an Excel form label caption text.
I'm using Shapes instead of Pictures and I tried to do the same with Shapes.AddLabel, but I can't make it.

This is the old code I had working with the COM object

```
With ExcelObject
    .ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.Label.1", Link:=False,
    DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=iTempLeft, Top:=iTempTop,
    Width:=iTempWidth, Height:=iTempHeight).Select() 
    iLabels = iLabels + 1
    sLabelName = "Label" & CStr(iLabels)
    .ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(sLabelName).object.Caption = gudtDrawingAndDefectXYsForPrint(iDrawing).sDrawingName
    .ActiveSheet.OLEObjects(sLabelName).Placement = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlacement.xlMoveAndSize 
End With
```

And now this is the updated code I tried to make for using the Interop

```
With ExcelObject
     CType(.ActiveSheet, Excel.Worksheet).Shapes.AddLabel(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, iTempLeft, iTempTop, iTempWidth, iTempHeight).Name = sLabelName
     CType(.ActiveSheet, Excel.Worksheet).Shapes.Item(sLabelName).Placement = Excel.XlPlacement.xlMoveAndSize
     CType(.ActiveSheet, Excel.Worksheet).Shapes.Item(sLabelName).Title = gudtDrawingAndDefectXYsForPrint(iDrawing).sDrawingName
End Width
```

The title won't display anything in screen as "Caption" did using COM object.

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to change the caption of Form Control and not ActiveX control?

Comment: Anyways.. I have given it for both...

Comment: We just don't want to use late binding, and the Form controls way to do that is working perfectly for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me. (*TESTED in VS 2010 Ultimate + Office 2010*)

**ACTIVEX CONTROLS**

```
    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlWb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlsheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim oleObj As Excel.OLEObject

    With xlApp
        .Visible = True

        xlWb = .Workbooks.Add

        xlsheet = xlWb.Sheets("Sheet1")

        With xlsheet
            oleObj = .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.Label.1", Link:=False,
                    DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=200, Top:=100,
                    Width:=100, Height:=35)

            oleObj.Object.caption = "Sid"
        End With
    End With
```

**FORM CONTROLS**

```
    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlWb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlsheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim Shp As Excel.Shape

    With xlApp
        .Visible = True

        xlWb = .Workbooks.Add
        xlsheet = xlWb.Sheets("Sheet1")

        With xlsheet
            Shp = .Shapes.AddLabel(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTextOrientation.msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 513, 128, 90, 27)

            Shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = "Sid"

        End With
    End With
```

Comment: Also works in VS2012 Pro + Office 2010 x86 + Win7 x64